# MySQL execute time

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help cutting the execution time on this query. 7 seconds seems too long for a table with 1500 rows.

```
  SELECT parent
    FROM video
   WHERE parent NOT IN (SELECT parent
                          FROM video
                         WHERE filename REGEXP '(s[0-9]{2}\e[0-9]{2})|([[:<:]][0-9]{3}[[:>:]])')
GROUP BY parent
```

Comment: Does the column `parent` have an index? Using regex in a query is probably also a reason why its slow.

Comment: @datasage: Correct, should've been an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you can use [`NOT REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_not-regexp) instead of a subquery.

```
SELECT parent
FROM video
WHERE filename NOT REGEXP '(s[0-9]{2}\e[0-9]{2})|([[:<:]][0-9]{3}[[:>:]])'
GROUP BY parent
```

**When using `REGEXP` or `NOT REGEXP`, the indexes don't matter.** To make it more efficient, if that's still not enough, you'll have to look at using other [string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html) or the `LIKE` operator.

Comment: Would this regex be faster with java? I did have everything being parsed through java with regex leaving clean data for my database, but with this new method using regex with queries, I've reduced the amount of code i need by about 50%..

Comment: @aLk: No, Java will never scale as well as the database can to large data sets.

Comment: @aLk - You could always pull all of the data in Java and use it's functions to sort the data. My advice is try using a single query (using `NOT REGEXP`) and do the same with all of the data using Java and time the execution. If you can run your script through a command line, the `time(2)` command might help.

Answer (score 2):

Two quick things:

- Ensure the `parent` column is indexed.
- Drop the regular expression. If you can, use `LIKE` or some other [string function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html).